# 802.1X wireless connection using iwctl

Tags: security, wifi, iwd

I am running Arch Linux and am using `iwctl` to connect to the Wi-Fi. 
I have tried to connect to a network that is using 802.1X security
and `iwctl` comes up with the error message “Not configured”. 
How do I configure `iwd` to work with this network?

The network also requires a username to login, not just a password.

Answer (score 2):

`iwd` can handle 802.1x authentication.  You will need to create a configuration file in `/var/lib/iwd/network_ssid.8021x`.  There, you'll specify your identity and passphrase in a manner that depends on the type of network you're connecting to.

See [iwd.network(5)](https://man.archlinux.org/man/iwd.network.5) for a description of the configuration file format, and the section of the [iwd arch wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Iwd#WPA_Enterprise) on connecting to WPA enterprise networks for a full description for various types of networks.

Answer (score 1):

https://iwd.wiki.kernel.org/networkmanager#converting_network_profiles

describes how `wpa_supplicant` profile(s) can be converted into `iwd` profile

Also it properly handles and encodes special char in SSID

> File naming and syntax
>
> File names are based on the network's SSID and security type: Open, PSK-protected or 802.1x. The name consist of the encoding of the SSID followed by .open, .psk or .8021x. The SSID appears verbatim in the name if it contains only alphanumeric characters, spaces, underscores or minus signs. Otherwise it is encoded as an equal sign followed by the lower-case hex encoding of the name.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is a working configuration file if you intend to connect to EduRoam(-like) networks (change `Identity` and `Password` to your needs):

```
[Security]
EAP-Method=TTLS
EAP-Identity=first.last@my.uni
EAP-TTLS-Phase2-Method=Tunneled-PAP
EAP-TTLS-Phase2-Identity=first.last@my.uni
EAP-TTLS-Phase2-Password=yourPassword

[Settings]
AutoConnect=true
```

Once written in `/var/lib/iwd/eduroam.8021x` (change `eduroam` to the SSID you want to connect), `iwd` will connect automatically!